# Unity! Few buttons are not responding, but others are working

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have 2 buttons that are not interactable for an unknown reason, other buttons work thow.
I have made a panel with multi-layered menu's which each contain buttons and text. You can cicle between layers by activating and deactivating menu's. Everything is a child of Canvas, also there is an EventSystem who is also a child of canvas. Everything has a RectTransform not a regular Transform. These buttons are practically identical to those that work. What could be the problem?

Using Unity version 2017.2.0f3

[Menu Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puw8P.png)

those buttons are called "Increase" and "Decrease":

Comment: EventSystem should not be under the Canvas. It should not have any parent to begin with. As foe you buttons not working, make sure that no other UI object is blocking them such as the Image component. Check it's parents and make sure they don't have anything attached to them that is blocking both buttons

Comment: Did all that, the thing is that before this 2 button problem I didn't even have even an EventSystem and all of the other buttons worked

Comment: I found the problem, the number display was blocking the buttons. It's because of the reverse UI rendering. This took me like 2 hours to figure out XD

Comment: Like I said, something(UI) is likely blocking it.

Comment: Thought that too at first because that was the most logical explanation but I couln't find what was blocking it

Comment: Disabling components attached to other objects is the easiest way to find the problem. Note for next time this happens

Comment: But there wasn't any other objects blocking it, The object was in a row after the buttons all children of the same parent

Comment: What I do to prevent this issue is to disable "IsRaycastTarget" on every UI element that don't need to be clicked.